# Continuous function induced by equivalence relation

Tags: metric-spaces, continuity

Let say $\sim$ is some equivalence relation defined on $\mathbb{R^n}$.
Define 
$$d_\sim:\mathbb{R^n}\times\mathbb{R^n}\to[0,\infty)\\d_\sim(v_1,v_2)=\inf_{w\in[v1],u\in[v_2]}\|w-u\|$$
([g]-the equivalence class of g).

What can I say about continuity of $d_\sim$? Is it continuous function? are there any conditions that might guarantee continuity? (anything you have in mind can help me)

Answer (score 2):

The function $d_\sim$ doesn't have to be continuous. Suppose that $n=1$ and that$$x\sim y\iff \lfloor x\rfloor=\lfloor y\rfloor.$$Then $\bigl(\forall x\in[-2,-1)\bigr):d_\sim(x,0)=1$, but $d_\sim(-1,0)=0$.